# Keep leading zeros when opening CSV files in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

When I open a CSV exported from SQLite, Microsoft Excel erases the zeros which are codes, e.g. 000.11 instead of 11.

How can I keep the leading zeros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the column as Text or change the format to display the number.
Reminder, the 0 at the left of number are not part of the number so 0001 is the number 1.
If in your application 0001 is different from 1 then you are dealing with strings (or text) not numbers ...

Comment: If they can control the format of the CSV they could precede their text field with a `'`. it will automatically be interpreted as text upon import.